# Copy Groovy Variable into File

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In groovy log info I need to copy Groovy variable data into one file.

```
log.info('duplicates' + duplicates);

def a = vars.get ("duplicate");

new File('/Duplicate.txt').with {
   delete()
  withWriter { w ->
      w.writeLine(a)  
  }
}
```

Facing with below issue:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: Seems like you are deleting the file itself instead of the file contents. Why don't you try to substitute the file contents with an empty `String` and then write the new content?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `duplicate` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) doesn't exist or hasn't been set.

If this question is a continuation of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109454/find-the-count-of-random-serial-numbers-from-response-data-and-find-duplicate-nu) you can write duplicate values into a file like:

```
def myFile = new File('Duplicate.txt')
if (myFile.exists()) {
    myFile.delete()
}
duplicates.unique().each { duplicate ->
    myFile << duplicate.value << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)